# Adding parameters to the link from the list?

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

I need to add to the link the data from the sheet, respectively, I need to create a `manufacturer-checkbox = firstParam & manufacturer = checkbox = secondParam&....`

This is my implementation:

```
<c:forEach items="${sessionScope.form.manufacturerList}" var="manufacturer">
             <a href="products?limit=${form.productMax}&sort=${form.sort}&price-form=${form.minPrice}&price-to=${form.maxPrice}&manufacturer-checkbox=${manufacturer}&categories-checkbox=${categoryList}">
        </c:forEach>
```

But in this implementation, only the last value is added to my manufacturer-checkbox field. How can manufacturer-checkbox be added depending on the number of elements in the manufacturerList? Now it creates two links with different manufacturer parameters, and I need to add parameters to one link, how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
<c:set var="manu-boxs" value=""/>
<c:forEach items="${sessionScope.form.manufacturerList}" var="manufacturer" varStatus="loop">
    <c:set var="param" value="manufacturer-checkbox-${manufacturer}">
    <c:set var="manu-boxs" value="${manu-boxs + param}"/>
</c:forEach>

<a href="products?limit=${form.productMax}&sort=${form.sort}&price-form=${form.minPrice}&price-to=${form.maxPrice}&categories-checkbox=${categoryList}&${manu-boxs}">
```

Use c:set to initailize original parameter list as empty, and add parameter by for-each loop. After that, you can get `manufacturer-checkbox-1`, `manufacturer-checkbox-2,` etc. as you want